# Azure Subscription

Tags: azure

Currently i am using Free Trial Subscription of Azure.

I am trying to use `Get-AzureVnetConfig -ExportToFile D:\NetworkConfig.Xml`
but it's asking for the Subscription, when i am putting the Subscription As Free Trial, its not working.

[image]

How do I get this command to work with a trial subscription?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but you are using the old ASM PowerShell commands. Unless you specifically created an old style vNet then you want the get-azurermvirtualnetwork command

Answer (score 0):

No default subscription has been designated.  Use

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName>
```

to set the default subscription.

Comment: Easier to read when it's not red on blue. ^_^